# About MongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am new to the NoSQL/MongoDB world and so I am experimenting with several things.

Let's say I would like to create a blog using MongoDB.

I could create a Blog post like this:

```
{
    Title: "My First Post",
    Body: "Bla de bla de bla bli bla de bah"
    Date: "07/07/2013" // or 06/07/2013 when using javascript date notation
}
```

And then I would like my readers to post comments. One thing I know about my readers is they get very involved. They write thousands of comments to my blog posts.

**First question:**
Is it a good idea to [embed](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#embedding) the comments? Or is it better to store them in their own collection with a reference to the blog post id?

Here's another example. Let's say I'd like to create a social media like web site that has several different types of objects (i.e.: blog posts, video's, contacts) and people can subcribe to the objects so they can comment and read other people's comments.

A comment feed would look like this:

```
{
    Type:[either blog post,video or contact]
    Name:"Comments on this crazy video"
    SubscribedUsers:[userid1,userid2,userid3...userid999]
    Comments: {
        {
            Name:"Purple Dog",
            Date: "07/07/2013 09:12:23",
            Text: "Bla bla bla"
        },
        {
            Name:"Shizzly Feather",
            Date: "07/07/2013 09:23:08",
            Text: "I agree with Purple Dog."
        }
    }
}
```

(maybe the notation is a bit off but I hope you get what I mean)

**Question two:**
Is the above example a good idea for a site like this? Is MongoDB a good fit or should I not use it for stuff like this? (What should I use then?) Or is there another way to achieve the same result (in the end, I would like to show the user an aggregated feed with all comments sorted by date DESC for the feeds they are subscribed to)

What I'm trying to learn (and what hopefully is useful to others) is when to choose MongoDB/NoSQL and when to stick with RDBMS's.

Comment: This basic question has been asked (and closed) many times on StackOverflow. You should start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongodB, you are better off embedding the comments because the comments are inextricably linked to each post - In fact, comments that are not germane/relevant to the post might be viewed as spam. The embedding shines when you ask for say, every comment that's associated with the post. The embedding sucks when you ask for say, every comment that's been made by anyone in the last 6 hours, but I can't think of a reason why you might want to ask for such a thing :)

You'll like RDBMS if you put the comments in their own table and you DO ask questions like "give me all comments that were made by everyone in the last six hours". On the other hand, RDBMS sucks when Julie C. (rightfully) expects to see all comments associated with her post and you have to run a "join" operation between the "poster" table, the "posts" table and the "comments" table to give her what she expects.

So, choose your poison :)

Comment: Thanks. In my second example I would do things like: get me all comments made by others on the objects I'm subscribed to. I think the second example is bad because it always loads all the comments even when I don't need them. But that's just my noob knowledge of this and that's why I would like to hear from the people who work with this on a regular basis

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another approach which is a hybrid called a bucketing strategy

http://www.slideshare.net/jrosoff/mongodb-advanced-schema-design-inboxes